# AWS load balanced server wordpress plugins super slow, on test server they are fast

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, wordpress

jetpack and offload S3 plugins of wordpress are slowing down our load balanced servers of AWS. That is: when connecting jetpack to a wordpress.com account, whopsie doopsie: response times increase by 2 to 3 seconds. Activating the Offload S3 plugins causes about another 2 seconds delay.

The site URL is
https://ironscales.com/

the test server that is not load balanced, does not have said issues:
http://testword.ironscales.com

what could be the problem? are we eventually blocking some ports and the plugins timeout on responses?

what can we do to debug the issue?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer as such, but the comments field is too small. Reviewers, please try to avoid the temptation of marking me down for trying to help.

Web page test for main site : [link](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/161201_HN_7382b4a29a1f9e8df7de27db30a31990/).
Web page test for test site: [link](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/161201_AH_9eaeaab9f20c346a7b3325d95214ebaa/).

Initial page generation time is the key issue. If this goes up when you add those two plugins then you'd need to look into why. There are Wordpress plugins that can help work this out, like [P3](https://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjnpNzrytPQAhUGmpQKHbN5BI0QFggZMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwordpress.org%2Fplugins%2Fp3-profiler%2F&usg=AFQjCNGFNreCL-hht-LBS7XElHvfMxtsTQ&sig2=8ZseNxuOSeOjaBaP1miUSw&bvm=bv.139782543,d.dGo). You also load a huge number of resources to display that page (135), and you're not using http/2 which could speed things up significantly. CloudFlare gives you http/2 free. You're not using a CDN.

I never use Jetpack, I just don't find it that useful. I use Nginx and page caching, which hugely increases response time for anonymous requests - which for you would be the majority.

I would:

1. Re-evaluate the need for load balancing. With Nginx / Apache caching in place (CloudFlare or similar is free and works) you would have to have a huge load in place to overwhelm a single AWS server - if you size it correctly.
2. Remove any plugins that aren't ESSENTIAL. Caching plugins can sometimes make things worse.
3. Reconsider S3 offload. That's only because you have load balancer servers. EFS is another possible solution.
4. Use P3 to track down what's going on. It could simply be latency.
5. Put page caching in place. If you use Nginx use [my tutorial](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-4-wordpress-website-optimization/) as a guide.
6. Try out HTTP2 - here's [my guide](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-5-free-https-https2-for-wordpress-using-lets-encrypt-aws/).

I'd also do some experimentation or research on the plugins that cause this problem. I tend to poke around and see what I find.

See my profile if you want to contact me directly, but I'll follow up this question here as well.

Comment: P3 was updated last 2 years ago... but i can give it a try.

Comment: and yes i just joined that project, the thing is: i told them the same about the load balancer not being necessary. They said they want to maybe keep it in case one of the servers goes down they can switch to the other one and thus have more uptime.

Comment: P3 was probably the least important part of my answer. P3 was an example, there are others. Disabling plugins that cause problems is higher up the list. Remove jetpack and use EFS instead of S3, problem solved. Also load balancer isn't a "switch to", it's "shared load". If they just want a backup that's different, easier - auto scaling with a min/max size of one, and a good updated AMI.

Comment: I guess we can somehow get rid of jetpack because they only use it to share posts. The S3 plugin: disabling it would mean having issues with the images.  With EFS you mean this? https://aws.amazon.com/efs/

Comment: probably you can configure to direct all requests to only one server if the second server is down, no? whereas when your single server crashes you first have to put the backup in place

Comment: Yes, Elastic File System. Basically you can put your whole Wordpress install on there, or just resources like images, so the web servers run off one file system. I assume you have a shared database server, RDS or similar. Yes with load balancing if one server goes down the other services all requests. With an AMI, auto scaling, min/max 1, there will be a period of a few minutes of downtime. You can also cache the pages to a CDN, so it will display the most recent if the server goes down.

Comment: I've had an AWS t2.micro that runs four moderate volume websites running for about a year with no outages, other than occasional reboots to update the kernel, which was not essential. High availability is good, but RTO/RPO needs to be considered. Wordpress isn't made to scale, but it can be made to scale.